# <p> at the bottom of div with no space

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position, absolute

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dL3667ss/

[image]

I have a `div` that contains an `img` and a `p`. The img is full size of the `div` and it's in grey. The `p` is the text in black absolutely positioned above the `img`.

I want the `p` text to be at the bottom of the `img`. The problem is that there's a space between them that I highlighted in red.

To solve that I can simply modify the `bottom` property in CSS, setting it to `bottom: -4px;`. But then I get another problem: in my PC it works (no space between) but in my cellphone it doesn't work. The space between them decreases but I still get some pixels of gap.

There is a way to take off this gap instead of using `bottom` property in negative value?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="myimg.jpg" class="image">
  <p class="title">
    My Title
  </p>
</div>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 45px;
  bottom: -4px;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
}
```

Comment: Try `line-height: 0.5`.

Comment: My answer specified 0.8em but you may wish to play with that value depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh.. add a `line-height` of `0.8em` on `.title`

```
.title{
    line-height: 0.8em; // ADDED THIS
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 45px;
    bottom: -4px;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just set bottom:-1% in title class

i have updated your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dL3667ss/6/

`bottom:-1%`